# jquery mobile pageContainer to load external page with transition effects

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am currently working on mobile application using jquery mobile v1.4.2 . . . . Almost all the functionality was done. now I want to add transition effects for all the pages ...

Question :
In jquery mobile v1.4.2 (doc) tells to use pageContainer instead of pagechange and pageload and I don't know how to load external page(another HTML file) with transition effect.I didn't find must example in google and any reference links is appreciated .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You can easily force default transition with this code:

   ```
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
   <script>
       $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
           $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'slide';
       });
   </script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
   ```

   Don't forget one thing, mobileinit event must be initialized BEFORE jQuery Mobile, just like in my example.
2. Regarding your second question, you will do it like this:

   ```
   $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "load", "second.html", { role: "page" } );
   ```

   Example:

   **index.html**

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
       <head>
           <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
           <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
           <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" /> 
           <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
           <script>
               $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
                   $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "slide";
               });            
           </script>
           <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
           <script>
               $(document).on('pagecreate', '#index', function(){ 
                   $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "load", "second.html", { role: "page" } );
               });     

           </script>       
       </head>
       <body>     
           <div data-role="page" id="index" data-theme="a" >
               <div data-role="header">
                   <h3>
                       First Page
                   </h3>
                   <a href="#second" class="ui-btn-right">Next</a>
               </div>

               <div data-role="content">

               </div>

               <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

               </div>
           </div>  
       </body>
   </html>
   ```

   **second.html**

   ```
   <div data-role="page" id="second" data-theme="a" >
       <div data-role="header">
           <h3>
               Second Page
           </h3>
           <a href="#index" class="ui-btn-left">Back</a>
       </div>

       <div data-role="content">

       </div>

       <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

       </div>
   </div>
   ```

Comment: thank for you response ... I replaced  window.location.href ="second.html" with pagecotainer that u given but its not working ...

Comment: I gave you a working example so problem is on your side. What's not working for you?

Comment: yes problem is from my side only ill find the solution thanks lot for giving nice example +1 ... thank lot gajotres

Comment: I am glad to be able to help :)

Comment: to load external page is there any code required to initialize, like this $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true; AND $.support.cors =true; in mobileinit

Comment: Thank you for this useful answer. It is a bit out of date - you need to replace `<div data-role="content">` with `<div role="main" class="ui-content">`. I see that **for the second HTML you do not put any headers**. Nobody was answering my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41654004/phonegap-cordova-jquerymobile-should-head-be-repeated-in-all-pages