# PhoneGap/Cordova + JQueryMobile: should HEAD be repeated in all pages?

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm doing my first steps in this environment and am trying to figure out the best practices. My app includes several HTML pages:

Should I duplicate the whole HEAD part into all the HTML pages,
 
Or maybe some of it is only required in the initial HTML page?

EXTRA

To my wonder I couldn't find an up-to-date example of a standard HTML header for such app, so with my question I'm also doing a share of knowledge.

Here is the header which, in my understanding, is required to allow the combination of JQM into PhoneGap:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' gap://ready file://* *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; media-src *">
    <title>JQM Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <!-- extra css for my app: -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <!-- include JQ, enable PhoneGap events under JQM, then include JQM: -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).on( "mobileinit", function() {
            $.support.cors = true;
            $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
            $.mobile.phonegapNavigationEnabled = true;
        });    
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Just for the completeness, in case you are wondering, the cordova part appears at the end of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    app.initialize();
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: Please do not downvote if this answer is wrong, but instead add a note explaining why it is wrong, so that we can all learn.

Nobody responded so I will put my *tentative* answer which I still need to verify.

In a normal **web app**, headers must be repeated because the user can **bookmark** a non-initial page, and get back to it later, so every page must be able to take the role of the initial page.

However with PhoneGap/Cordova we can ensure a specific page is loaded on startup, and this way, because pages are loaded using ajax, we might be able to skip the include parts of the other pages.